# Use UID for topics IOS

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, uid

Im rather new to Firebase. Im trying to achieve the following all within IOS

When a user adds a record to the database they will receive a push notification alerting them that a record has been added.. Yes I do want to send a notification to the user who added their own record!

How can this be achieved so only the user who added the record will receive the notification?

I've been messing around with topics.. But all users seem to receive the notification when a record is added

I some how need to create a link where only the UID of each user will listen out for changes

Any help is appreciated, And please ask for more details if needed

Thanks
Oliver!

Comment: Hi Oliver. Your post is a bit too broad. But I get the idea. When saving data, I assume you'll be using Firebase Database, in which case, you could just take advantage of an `EventListener` of some sort for iOS to let the user know that a data has been updated. If you still insist on using FCM, dont use topics. Topics was meant to be used for sending messages publicly -- to every subscribers of that topic to be specific. I would also suggest looking in Cloud Functions for Firebase to do this.

Comment: If you create a topic for each user (e.g. based on their UID) and then subscribe each user to only their own topic, you can make sure they get (only) their own notifications. Just be aware that topics are public: anyone can subscribe to a topic if they know its name.